# JavaScript - more efficient way to truncate an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an int array sorted ascending and I would like to remove array items from the tail according to the specific boundary. What is a better way to truncate an array in my case? Consider next code snippets:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var length = a.length;
var boundary = 2;
var count = 0;
for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (a[i] > boundary) {
        a[i] = null; // or delete a[i] ???
        count++;
    }
}
a.length -= count;
```

Or the same but using *splice*:

```
for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (a[i] > boundary) {
        a.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Those two snippets of code do very different things, and neither of them remove elements that are only on the tail. To see what I mean, use `[4, 3, 2, 1]` as your array.

Comment: My array is always sorted ascending.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that detail. You should be using a binary search then.

Comment: Good point! Didn't think about that but need to give it a try!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 a.length -= count;
```

Thats sufficient ;) (as length is not a simple property, but rather a getter/setter which truncates/adds elements [(ref)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length))

Alternatively use splice:

```
 a.splice(-count, count);
```

Comment: Can you explain why? What is happening under the hood?

Comment: @Alex It's probably similar to `splice()`, but it doesn't need to create an array of the removed elements, or worry about shifting the elements after the splice down.

Comment: If I interpreted the OPs question correctly, he wants to delete the `x` tail elements which are `> boundary`, not specifically #`count` elements. `count` is just a variable he used to track how many elements were `> boundary` in the first snippet. `a.length -= count;` is already exactly what he does in that sample, once he has determined the number of elements to remove, but that is not already known.

Comment: @Paulpro You are right, `count` is a way to track the number of elements that I want to cut off from the tail.

Comment: @paulpro imo the real question is `a[i] = null; // or delete a[i] ???` which ive answered above

Comment: @JonasW. That line doesn't matter, it's basically a no-op, because the array is shortened after anyway, only the `count++` in that loop matters.

Comment: To answer the OP question: `splice` is faster. https://jsperf.app/savira

Answer (score 2):

In modern engines, or with a shim, you can use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var boundary = 2;
a.length = a.findIndex( x => x > boundary );
console.log( a );
```

Since you're array is sorted you can also just use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var boundary = 2;
a = a.filter( x => x <= boundary );
console.log( a );
```

which may be slightly (negligibly) slower if the array is huge, but has more support in older engines.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete array entries at the end of an array to truncate it. Deleting array entries removes them from the array by creating a sparse array: the `length` property of the array remains unchanged:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
console.log( "a.length %s", a.length);
delete a[3];
console.log( "a[3] after deletion: %s", a[3]);
console.log( "a.length after deletion %s", a.length);
console.log( "a[3] still exists: %s", a.hasOwnProperty("3"));
```

Similar considerations apply to setting array entries to `null`. They will no longer test as truthy in a conditional expression, but have not been removed. As before the length of the array will remain unchanged.

Setting the length of the an array to something shorter than its existing value will truncate it in place. There are many ways of finding the boundary position at which to truncate the array. I suggest choosing one that appears natural to you and works in target browsers. E.G. using `forSome` on a sorted array may not meet your requirements :)

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var boundary = 2;
a.some(
   (c,i) => {
      if( c > boundary)
      {  a.length = i;
         return true;
      }
   }
);

console.log( a)
```

If using `splice`, note that all entries from the boundary position to the end of array can be deleted in one call rather than deleting them one at a time:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var boundary = 2;
for( var i = a.length-1; a[i]>boundary; --i) {} // linear search
a.splice(i+1);
console.log(a);
```